# Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics

Tags: discussion, nominations

**I've made a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75851/proposed-statistics-page-to-accompany-nominations) out of this**

I found myself doing lots of clicking through to profiles to try and compare nominees with (what I consider to be) useful/interesting information.

I've cobbled together an Excel file with some metrics, may help you with your decision, and possible inspire the dev team to put together something like this to help inform the democratic process...

Google doc published as web page [here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0Au7emdPoZMdbdHJObExWMmpidkJlTDN4Zm53R1ZlSEE&hl=en&single=true&gid=0&output=html): **EDIT, no don't bother, just jump straight to the link in YiJiang's answer (and give him all the votes he deserves!)**

**Can we squeeze a question out of this? :)**

I'd be interested to know which of theses metrics you think are useful, and if you think they ought to be included automatically into nominee info in the election process.

Comment: Warning: Nominations are changing fast, and I won't be up all night to update it...

Comment: nice compilation @Benjol

Comment: I think age and location should be the least important.  Also, I think your MSO chat stats are wrong.  I've been on MSO chat far more than SO chat, but you have me listed as 0.  Also, votes per answer, would be a cool statistic.  Not sure how helpful that would be though...

Comment: @Justin, age and location both had ? in my original 'feature list' :) Location is mostly for timezone interest. Sorry 'bout your chat stat, fixed, according to Google Docs available in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Benjol, also, you should order by rep, and number the list.  There are only 30 spots in the primary.

Comment: But, I should mention that it is a good spreadsheet.  Makes it easier to view candidates.

Comment: @Justin, ordering by rep is biasing the data, it's currently ordered by inverse order of arrival, and I just left the bumped ones for comparison...

Comment: @benjol, ok.  That makes sense.

Comment: Most SE accounts! I should win automatically

Comment: @Michael, wasn't that what I said? (Oops! :)

Comment: You should update with current mod info, for comparison.

Comment: @Will, suggestion transmitted to @Yi

Comment: Starting bounty to award it to @YiJiang in 24 hours.

Answer (score 91):

> #### Update: Please use the [Stack Apps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/2049/stack-exchange-elections-statistics-page) for bug reports, feature requests etc, the comment thread here is getting a little long.

Ah right, the page Benjol was talking about in the comments is about finished. It pulls in a pretty impressive amount of information by using an obscene amount of API calls to the Stack Overflow API. It's all client-side, so please do not set it to auto-refresh every minute, or else it will eat through a lot of unnecessary API calls.

The page itself isn't heavy at all, but as stated above, the script pulls in a large amount of data, so it will take some time to load - the last few sections may take up to half a minute to fill.

With all that aside, you can find the page here:

### [Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics](http://elections.stackexchange.com/)

**Update:** Now working for all sites!
**Update 2:** Local cached copies now available for all sites. Click on the *"static cached version"* button to toggle between the live and cached version. There's also a button on the footer that allows you to save a copy of the page yourself.
**Update 3:** Moved over to an actual server, kindly provided by [Dan Grossman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152451/dan-grossman), since the Dropbox link is erroring out (probably under the load). Please use the new link from now on.
**Update 4:** Now with [official sanction](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/)!
**Update 5:** Now with [even more official sanction](http://elections.stackexchange.com/)!!

As usual, all comments and suggestions welcome, especially which data you might want to see appear there.

Comment: Could you add sorting?  Rep, site age, rep per post, etc...

Comment: +1000 if I could. @Pekka, you know where to leave your bounty!

Comment: @Justin'jjnguy'Nelson That was on my list for quite a while now. In fact, I've had http://razorjack.net/quicksand/ open for several hours now :P Just a little busy with the other features

Comment: @YiJi, well get your priorities in order.  I COME FIRST. `:P`

Comment: Does this have to be regenerated for every person who loads it? Can the data be fetched once (or once a day) and kept as a static page?

Comment: Is it just me, or is anyone else not seeing any actual data on this page?  I just see a title and a description paragraph.  At the bottom there's a request to Yahoo APIs but even after 10 minutes of waiting, nothing has changed on the page.

Comment: @Aarobot, not just you. I've never had any problems, but others have reported no - or partial - results. @Yi's looking into it (or rather, he will be, when he wakes up :)

Comment: it works like a charm

Comment: This works beautifully on FF, but just dies without displaying anything on Chrome 8.(chrome version of the day)

Comment: Works in FF for me too, but not Safari. Is this a WebKit incompatibility?

Comment: I just created a static version of of the page. It won't be updated as frequently (*at least* once per day) but it should work for those of you who can't get the thing to load. I'm sorry to say that, given that this is built in JavaScript, there isn't a very good way of automatically generating the cached version

Comment: @YiJiang, would it be possible for you to release a version of this which works for the Super User and Server Fault elections, too? If you don't want to do the work of putting in all the users (if it doesn't grab them automatically, not sure how it works internaly), I'd be happy to provide you a list of UIDs for the users who've nominated themselves so far.

Comment: @nhinkle Sure, I think I can - it'll just be as simple as changing a few URLs around. Hang on while I finish what I'm doing now and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @YiJiang, thanks for the quick and accommodating reply! Wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: @nhinkle Well, it wasn't as simple as changing a few URLs around, but it should work now - go test it out.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - I really appreciate all the time and work you've put into this. However I'm still one of the people that's having the issue where I'm just getting a blank page, and there's no cached version of the other sites to view (and `a.results[0] is undefined` in the FF error console in `plugins.js`)

Comment: @Farseeker Looks like the error is coming out of the X-domain ajax plugin I'm using to grab the election page. Can you check the Firebug net panel to see if it's a network error that's causing this?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - full of 200's and 304's which is what I would expect to see. The requested AJAX url is [this](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=jsonp1295587062383&q=select+*+from+html+where+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Felection%3Ftab%3Dnomination%22+and+xpath%3D%22*%22&format=xml) - which returns an empty result array. (note: the comment markup removed the `*` from between 'select++from' - it is being requested though)

Comment: @Farseeker I'm not entirely sure why it's happening, but YQL is returning nothing in your case. I've added a check for whether the `result` array is empty, but that doesn't solve the actual problem, that is YQL returning nothing. I have no idea why that would be happening, so I can't help you on that count.

Comment: @Yi - no worries. I suspect my local yahoo server is mis configured or something, which is why it happens to some and not others. It's probably a geo-related issue.

Comment: Holy crap, its beautiful.  I'm making a note here: huge success!

Comment: This page is awesome!  Great work!

Comment: @YiJiang is it possible to have cached versions for each of the trilogy sites ? The live site doesn't seem to load at all, the results is an empty array - http://i.imgur.com/w8zAo.png. Thanks!

Comment: @Sathya I've added local copies for all sites, now that I've got a better mechanism for generating local copies. See if it works for you.

Comment: @YiJiang works great, thank you!

Comment: **Reticulating Spline** is awesome. Reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimCity_2000) and [here at 0:14](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn9nN5NxOK8&feature=related).

Comment: @Yi Jiang are you planning on being able to pull the votes and sort by vote?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That's already done :) Go have a look at it now

Comment: @Yi Jiang +1 Awesome.

Comment: Yi Jiang, in case you don't visit there, [The Community Duck from Game Dev](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/366/information-on-the-moderator-candidates/367#367) has suggested that the badge descriptions should be somehow visible - I imagine a tooltip might suffice.

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  The tool seems to get to `Loading elections page` (with a green check), then hang this morning (but not yesterday).  Is it just me?

Comment: @C.Ross Works for me, sorry. Have you tried force reloading with  `ctrl` + `f5`?

Comment: @GraceNote Will add them later, if I have the time

Comment: @Yi Jiang Still the same.  May be a firewall issue for all I know.

Comment: @C.Ross Check the browser dev tool's (Firebug for Firefox, `ctrl + shift + I` for Chrome and Opera) net or resources tab (activate before loading) for network errors, or the console tab for js errors

Comment: @Yi Jiang: found a potential bug, check this out on the P.SE chat. Thanks for the great work!

Comment: @Yi Jiang -- I have no interest in nominating myself for moderatership, but I'd love to be able to see my own statistics in the same manner displayed of the candidates. How difficult would it be to display that same information if you input, say, a particular user name?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'll try to implement that feature today, if possible

Comment: Thanks for putting the statistic site online, @Yi Jiang. However there seems to be a bug or at least an delay with the "Sportsmanship" badge. For tex.sx it doesn't show up while three candidates got it (Some just recently). See [this meta.tex.sx discussion](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/961/2975) for more.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if people could link directly to the statistic of their SX site, e.g. allow the site to be added as `/<name>` or `?site=<name>` to the URL. Thanks again!

Comment: @MartinScharrer The first might be a bug with the API, I'm not sure, I'll have to check the data here. The second suggestion is a little hard to do since the entire page is only a static HTML page that's not powered by any server-side stuff (bad choice here to develop this whole thing in client side JavaScript, yes, but it's what I'm most comfortable working with here, so that what we're stuck with)

Comment: @YiJiang: Thanks for the fast answer. To 1.: Are you using the dumped data from `data.sx` or the current values? To 2.: Could you not read out some `?site=<name>` variable on the URL with JavaScript?

Comment: @MartinScharrer It's not a bug with the API, I'm investigating this now

Comment: @MartinScharrer 1. It's not using a data dump or anything like that, the info provided by the API is updated live; 2. I can, it's just that the landing page does contain the option to modify the list of badges to watch which some might want to use

Comment: @YiJiang: Thanks for having a look on that issue. Great site!

Comment: @MartinScharrer Found the bug, incredibly stupid mistake there. Do a `ctrl + f5` to clear the cache, and you should see it working now

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Thanks!! Works fine now.

Comment: Hi @YiJiang - Excellent app. is there any chance of updating it for itsecurity and bicycles.SE sites as their election nominations have just opened and it would be really good to have the stats for these two.

Answer (score 2):

I think anyone who wants to be a moderator should have demonstrated extensive participation in SO already. That includes **voting**, making **useful comments**, **editing**, etc. I believe anyone who has trouble with those duties is going to struggle as a moderator. Is there a way to collect stats on these? (So far I've just been checking the nominees for badges like Strunk & White or Pundit.)

Comment: Good idea.  Strung and White, Copy-Editor, Pundit (maybe), Electorate (Maybe), Civic Duty.  Those all show community participation besides reputation earning.

Comment: @Justin Right, I've been checking for all of those plus Sportsmanship. I know I can query for badges through SE's data export, but I'd still need the list of nominees for an automated report.

Comment: @chris, I forgot about Sportsmanship.  That's another good one.

Comment: I'm strongly in favor of seeing both total numbers of votes as well as the ratio. Personally, I'm looking for a moderator that has voted a lot, and has not been afraid to downvote.

Comment: @Phrogz define not afraid to downvote? 10% is there a metric? Is it just a gut? More than 1% and less than 5%?

Comment: @drachenstern As a crotchety bastard, I would actually look for 50%-100% as many downs as ups.

Comment: @all, YiJiang is working on an automated version of my file, I'm feeding your 'requirements' to him, so keep 'em coming :)

Comment: @Benjol Ah, great. Basically I'd want to see which *silver and gold participation badges* a nominee has. (So ignore bronze badges, tag badges, and any questions or answers badges.) I'm looking to gauge participation rather than technical competence, which is already factored-in with the top-30-by-rep requirement.

Comment: @chrisaycock, agreed. Looking at the list as it stands, the rep/gold ratio is quite variable. I'm not sure that *which* gold/silver badges is interesting - there's a high chance it wil be in the user's top tags (which are shown).

Answer (score 2):

Would probably be useful to expand the notable badges to include the new Review badges (Steward, Reviewer, Custodian)!

Comment: Please use the [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/2049/stack-exchange-elections-statistics-page) page for bug reports, feature requests etc, the comment thread here is getting a little long :)

Comment: Might be worth copying the "update" block into the question and getting this locked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Flag weight. I know you can't display it, but still...

Comment: Don't forget to tell @Yi :)