# Proposed statistics page to accompany nominations

Tags: feature-request, election, nominations

Building on [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75454/moderator-nomination-possibly-useful-statistics), and more importantly on Yi Jiang's most excellent implementation, the feature request is simply that something like this should be implemented into SE for future elections.

Comment: Just a note, I think we exceeded Dropbox's limit for downloading the file as I'm only getting errors on it

Comment: @Ivo, try refreshing, worked on the 3rd try for me :)

Comment: It's working again then ;-)

Comment: @Ivo, new hosting, I won't link from here in case the url changes again, but see @Yi's answer on my previous question.